# SQL import 10000+ .csv files

Tags: sql, csv, import, bulk

Unfortunately I have had issues with my storage and was forced to reacquire data.  However, this came in many `.csv` files and don't know how to import all of them without doing it one by one. I would like to have the 10000+ `.csv` files into one table and would like help with coding all imports one time.

All of the files have the same schema:

```
'Symbol' (varchar(15))
'Date' (Date)
'Open' (Float)
'High' (Float)
'Low' (Float)
'Close' (Float)
'Volume' (Int)
```

Also: All files will have the same structure for their naming:

```
XXXXXX_YYYYMMDD
```

(XXXXXX is the name of the market; I have 7 unique names)

```
Create Table [investment data 1].dbo.AA 
(
    Symbol varchar(15),
    [Date] Date,
    [Open] Float,
    High Float,
    Low Float,
    [Close] Float,
    Volume Int
)
```

At this point I do not know how to generate a loop that will look at all files in the "Investment Data" folder; the below example is the sample code for one .csv file.  If there is a better way than "bulk insert" then I will modify the statement below.

```
bulk insert [investment data 1].dbo.AA
    from 'R:\Investment Data\NASDAQ_20090626.csv'
with
(
    firstrow=2
    ,rowterminator = '\n'
    ,fieldterminator = ','
)
```

Any help is appreciated; if I can be more clear please let me know.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you concatenate all the files together outside the database?

Comment: In order to create your loop you should to create an script with powershell or something else like python or bash and import all files. If you have issues with your script, don't hesitate to post problems here. Also, remember [how to ask good quesions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does what you wrote (for that one file) work ?

Great.

- Open a dos prompt
- Navigate to the folder with your 10,000 files
- type `DIR /b >c:\temp\files.txt`
- Now install a decent text editor, like Notepad++  (these instructions are for notepad ++)
- Open c:\temp\files.txt in that editor
- Open the find/replace dialog, place a tick next to "Extended (\n, \r..." - this makes it match newlines, and support newlines in replacements
- Put this in Find: `\r\n`
- Put this in Replace: `' with(firstrow=2,rowterminator = '\\n',fieldterminator = ',');\r\nbulk insert [investment data 1].dbo.AA from 'R:\Investment Data\`

This will make your list of files that used to look like this:

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
d.txt
```

Look like this:

```
a.txt' with(firstrow=2,rowterminator = '\n',fieldterminator = ',')
bulk insert [investment data 1].dbo.AA from 'R:\Investment Data\b.txt' with(firstrow=2,rowterminator = '\n',fieldterminator = ',');
bulk insert [investment data 1].dbo.AA from 'R:\Investment Data\c.txt' with(firstrow=2,rowterminator = '\n',fieldterminator = ',');
bulk insert [investment data 1].dbo.AA from 'R:\Investment Data\d.txt' with(firstrow=2,rowterminator = '\n',fieldterminator = ',');
bulk insert [investment data 1].dbo.AA from 'R:\Investment Data\
```

Now just clean up the first and last lines so it's a proper SQL. Paste and run in SSMS

Comment: I do a lot of things like this - particularly for once-off jobs. I'd do it with notepadd++ too, but using a regular expression search/replace. Just get the list of files you got in files.txt, search for the regex `^(.*)$` and change it to your bulk insert line replacing the filename with `\1`

Comment: Another way indeed to skin the cat. These days I'd probably use sublime text editor, and the multi cursors feature, but that would take more explaining/more to go wrong :)

Comment: I appreciate this solution; for me I just manipulated in excel; that way if I need to modify the syntax statement multiple times I just adjust a concatenation formula (vice find and replace, screw it up, open another notepad++ and repeat all of the prior find/replace, etc.).  That said, notepad ++ is excellent and I will be using in the future.